# Error Deploying Static Web App to Azure (React) Using Git Hub

Tags: reactjs, github, yaml, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to Deploy a React App to a Static Web App in Azure, using my GitHub repository.

When I look in the actions in Git Hub and view the delopment run it fails.

This is the error that I see:

```
    Running 'npm install --unsafe-perm'...

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   7 more (html-react-parser, react-dom, react-helmet, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!   react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-typed@1.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typed
npm ERR!     react-typed@"^1.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /github/home/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2022-11-28T18_21_32_391Z-debug-0.log


---End of Oryx build logs---
Oryx has failed to build the solution.
```

Can anyone suggest why my build is failing and how to fix it?

This is what the yml work flow looks like:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN }}
          action: "close"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps to deploy `React app` to `Azure Static Web App`

- In file explorer create a folder with name `reactstatic`.
- In `VSCode`, open the `new terminal` and run the below command to create a new react app.

```cs
npx create-react-app ./
```

[image]

Thanks @Christian Glessner for the [Git Repo](https://github.com/ltwlf/react-static-web-app)

- In GitHub, create a new repository.
- From VS Code, push the newly created app to GitHub
- In Azure Portal, create a Static Web App using `GitHubAccount` with the below given values.

[image]

- In GitHub,`workflows` folder will be created.

[image]

- Check whether the build is success or not in GitHub -
  `https://github.com/Organization/YourAppName`
  Click on `Actions` => `Build and Deploy Job`

[image]

- Now we can Open the `Static Web App` in Portal and access the `Url`.

[image]

> Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

To fix the error, as mentioned in the error itself
run the below command

```js
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i
```

To fix the error, as mentioned in the error itself
run the below command

```js
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i
```

- If you still face the issue, delete the `node_modules` folder ,`package-json.lock` file and run the above command again.